# Swift + Xcode 6 beta 3 + Core Data = awakeFromInsert not called?

Tags: xcode, core-data, swift

Need help.

I'm creating new Document-based Core Data Cocoa project.
Add entity named 'Entity' into the core data model. Add 'creationDate' propery into it and set its type as Date. And create NSManagedObject subclass from 'Editor' menu.

Now I add into 'Entity.swift' file this code:

```
override func awakeFromInsert()  {
    super.awakeFromInsert()
    self.creationDate = NSDate()
    println("awakeFromInsert called")
}
```

Now in my NSPersistentDocument subclass I write such a init() method:

```
init() {
    super.init()

    var context = self.managedObjectContext
    context.undoManager.disableUndoRegistration()
    var entity = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Entity", inManagedObjectContext: context)
    context.processPendingChanges()
    context.undoManager.enableUndoRegistration()

    println("\(entity)")
}
```

Everything compiles... BUT awakeFromInsert is never called! The interesting part is that 'entity' object ain't nil! It was created, but not initialized. And if I write this line in init method

```
entity.creationDate = NSDate()
```

then creationDate property will be set to a current date as expected.

But that's not all. If I debug execution step-by-step I can see that execution enters 'Entity.swift' file, but starts from the top of the file, then immediately drops and returns back to the NSPersistentDocument subclass file.

Tell me, is it a bug? Because I'm tired to fight with this nonsense. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accidentally I got it work: you have to add @objc(YourSubclass) before subclass declaration. I usually did @objc class MySubclass and turned out it does not work (don't know why).

WORKING:

```
@objc(YourSubclass)
class YourSubclass : NSManagedObject {
...
```

NOT WORKING:

```
@objc class YourSubclass : NSManagedObject {
...
```

Comment: are you also decorating the name of the class in your core data model file?

Comment: Not sure, I get it. Both names are identical

Comment: I am very curious a) why this worked, and b) why this is still solving my problem in 2021. Thanks!

Comment: This works because of the internal namespacing of the Obj-C code. Apparently, CoreData code is still translated into Obj-C code internally and you need not only the @objc declaration to make it possible but also to specify the translated class name in parentheses, otherwise, the translated code will be messed up with the namespaces.

Comment: Interesting. I have since learned that the alternative is to specify the fully resolved subclass name in Core Data, including the Swift namespace, i.e. `MyProjectName.MySubclassName`. But I prefer to override the ObjC name as per here instead. :)